# Displaying degrees on map axes using coord_sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am making a map and wanted to use an alternative projection. When I do this using `coord_sf`, the x- and y-axes get labels of some other units like 0.001°W. I'm not a geographer, so I'm not sure what these are. I'd like to just see degrees latitude and longitude...

Code to generate the basic map:

```
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray70", fill="gray70") 
ggplot() + mapWorld +  coord_sf(xlim=c(-125, 155),ylim=c(-22,40), crs = "+proj=laea")
```

Resulting plot:

[image: map projection]

Comment: You are probably looking for this function from the 'biogeo' package:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/biogeo/versions/1.0/topics/dms2dd

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think that is quite what's missing. The display is in some other units (note 0.001°W where it should be like 100). Hmm, maybe I need to multiply by 100,000.

Comment: that's like the kindest bounty I've seen so far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way of fixing your problem here is to simply remove the reprojection. The reason you are seeing funny coordinates is that you supplied a different coordinate reference system through `coord_sf(...)`.

```
#install.packages('maps')
mapWorld <- borders("world",colour="gray70", fill="gray70") 
ggplot() + mapWorld + coord_sf(xlim=c(-125, 155),ylim=c(-22,40))
```

[image]
The more complicated answer relates to whether you want to use a different projection system. Where you have `coord_sf(xlim=c(-125, 155),ylim=c(-22,40), crs = "+proj=laea")` you are applying a modification to `geom_sf` to use a different projection of the map. Your code `laea` I assume refers to the [Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection) projection centred on Europe, right? [That one has CRS code 3035](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-laea/).

Where you will run into a problem, though, is that in order to apply a spatial projection, you need to be working with a spatial object, not a picture of a map. 
When you call: `borders("world",colour="gray70", fill="gray70")` you are using a quick hack in `ggplot2` to get simple x and y values from the data in the `maps` package. The problem is that `borders()` doesn't take projection as an argument when it retrieves data from the `maps` package, so it only takes simple x(long) and y(lat) values and turns it into a dataframe.

Now, you *can* reproject and plot a map using just the `maps` (and `mapproj`) packages. If you check out the documentation on `maps::map` it shows you can supply a `projection = ...` argument, but the projections are limited to the ones included in `mapproj`. For example, you could use an Azimuth Equal Area projection:

```
map("world", projection = "azequalarea", xlim = c(-125,155), ylim = c(-22,40))
```

[image]
And it would look like this, which is kind of ugly. You can modify how it is centred, etc, but it still won't look that great. Which shouldn't be that surprising as you're using a library that *predates* R itself, coming from the language S.

You could approach this using more modern tools that give you a lot more flexibility. `geom_sf` in ggplot is designed to work with spatial objects, ideally in `sf` format, but it is easy to convert between different kinds of spatial objects. Here's a quick example how to make the map you have in mind.

First, let's get a map of the world as a spatial data object

```
#install.packages('rnaturalearth')
#install.packages('rnaturalearthdata')
#install.packages('sf')
#install.packages('rgeos')

library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sf)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
> world
Simple feature collection with 241 features and 63 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -180 ymin: -89.99893 xmax: 180 ymax: 83.59961
CRS:            +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
First 10 features:
```

This object has a projection attached
`CRS:+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0`. Which is essentially the default projection when working with latitude and longitude, and what most people are used to. We can plot this:

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() + 
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

[image]
Now that it is a spatial data object, it's easy to change projections or to customize it based on elements within the data. For example, using the LAEA projection code (3035) and adding colours. for different continents:

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = continent)) + 
  coord_sf(crs = 3035)
```

[image]
If you still want to have boundaries like `xlim=c(-125, 155),ylim=c(-22,40)`, you need to be mindful about what those numbers represent when dealing with other projections. Those numbers refer to lat/lon values, but when we're using other projections we have to use the units those projections are in. You would have to reproject those limits into coordinates used by that specific projection; however, based on the limits you've set, I would suggest they will not work well at all with this type of projection. I would advise you to stick with lat/long, i.e. `CRS = 4326` if you want your map to look like what you had in mind.

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() + 
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") + coord_sf(xlim=c(-125, 155),ylim=c(-22,40))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and answer — practically a tutorial. I did want to have the option of using other projections (perhaps not LAEA in the end). I will try your suggestion of using a more rigorous definition of the map object via `geom_sf`.

Comment: I guess I could zoom and crop the image instead of specifying the bounds?

Comment: Given your walk-through as a starting point, I'll try the visual cropping methods shown here: https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2019/04/30/zooming-in-on-maps-with-sf-and-ggplot2/  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm going to unaccept your answer *for the moment* in case someone has a quick recipe for getting degrees to show up on the maps that use meters for units.

Comment: There’s a very quick fix at the top of the post for your original map

Comment: Yes, I had the original map working in standard projection, but curious about labeling grid on alt projections?